Trying to customize the T-shirt print
So, I'm trying to customize a stamp onto a shirt. I did the UV Mapping but when I upload the image in my software for it to be applied to the shirt, this happens:

Beside the shirt there's another object that went correct. It is not my object and I'm using it as reference.
This is just a draft but I want the image to appear this way on the shirt.

On my software, I upload the .mtl and the .obj. I use the OBJLoader from threejs to do this.
Can someone help me with this? Thanks!
Blend file: https://files.catbox.moe/hyynml.blend (80 MB)

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Sure, here it is: files.catbox.moe/hyynml.blend , I just couldnt upload at the mentioned site because my project is larger than 20mb. And I'm a total newbie at blender  so sorry for the mess.

It could be z-fighting because the print is a separate object and you have shrink-wrapped it on the shirt. If you switch to Solid shading mode (key Z) and zoom out a bit you will see something similar in Blender. (However, it does not happen in render mode.). I recently saw this “shrink wrap” technique being used for customizing game models. Do you need the ability to swap out the print, or would it be ok to bake it onto the shirt (texture baking)?

Hello and thanks for the help! Basically, when I upload an image into my software, it reflects at the shirt's print. I don't know if the baking could invalidate this idea. But the object beside the shirt works perfectly when uploading an image and I dont know what I did different for the Shirt not work.

Also, I tried to create a distance between both objects of the shirt and it keeps happening: https://imgur.com/wDdjhsJ

The cylinder has a lot less vertices than the shirt and it's only one object. The shirt and the stamp are high-poly (not sure if this is relevant). With the distance, it still looks odd. But apparently, it's not z-fighting. In which format do you export the models? I've just exported it as glTF 2.0, imported it into https://threejs.org/editor/ and set the Environment to Modelviewer. It looks good. You could paint/bake the print on the shirt, ignore/delete the print object (OBJ.001), and see if this works.
